# Infinite loop of Resetting offset and seeking for LATEST offset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to execute a simple spark structured streaming application which for now does not do much expect for pulling from a local Kafka cluster and writing to local file system. The code looks as follows:

```
    private static final String TARGET_PATH = "orchestration/target/myfolder/";

    private static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVER = "localhost:9092";
    private static final String KAFKA_TOPIC = "twitter_aapl2";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException, StreamingQueryException {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("spark app").getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
                .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC)
                .load();

        StreamingQuery query = df.writeStream()
                .outputMode("append")
                .format("parquet")
                .option("path", TARGET_PATH + "data/")
                .option("checkpointLocation", TARGET_PATH + "checkpoints/")
                .start();
        query.awaitTermination();
```

But on execution I get the following output and my data ain't really getting processed.

```
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition twitter_aapl2-0 to offset 128.
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition twitter_aapl2-0
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition twitter_aapl2-0 to offset 128.
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition twitter_aapl2-0
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition twitter_aapl2-0 to offset 128.
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition twitter_aapl2-0
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition twitter_aapl2-0 to offset 128.
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition twitter_aapl2-0
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition twitter_aapl2-0 to offset 128.
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition twitter_aapl2-0
21/01/20 16:54:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-13ec7de0-97da-499c-a507-d8e4baa764dd-1008481407-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition twitter_aapl2-0 to offset 128.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sending data into the topic after you run this structured streaming job or have you already written data in the topic and after that starting this job? Also, have you tried deleting your checkpointLocation folder?

Comment: Based on the output, 128 is the latest offset. If you want existing data to be processed, you'll need another option to do so

Comment: Hi mike and OneCricketeer. I've checked and removed the output folder (including checkpoints) of the application as well as deleting all Kafka and Zookeeper data. Then I started the services anew, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 4):

I had to avoid this by setting log config:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState=WARN
```

Although this is expected behavior, it seems unnecessary to log 'Seeking to LATEST offset' message every few milliseconds. It obscures all other application logs in the log file. This issue becomes even more concerning when consuming from topics that are not very active all the time. Better if it was just at DEBUG level instead of INFO.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this behaviour of seeking and resetting is perfectly desirable in case that one does not read to the topic from beginning, but from latest offset. The pipeline then only reads new data that gets sent to the Kafka topic whilst it is running and since no new data was sent, the infinite loop of seeking (new data) and resetting (to latest offset).

Bottom line, just read from beginning or send new data and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just because of verbose logging from Kafka Consumers [SubscriptionState](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/SubscriptionState.java#LL390)

If you are using Spark 3.3.x with log4j2 setup (default), then the following might work for you

Add the following snippet to your `$SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j2.properties`

```
# Settings to quiet Kafka consumer logs that is too verbose
logger.kafkaConsumer.name = org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer
logger.kafkaConsumer.level = warn
```